# How to choose bracing type and location

Tags: structural-engineering

I was given a question (see image: elevation) and was asked which type of bracing (the bottom 3 types: v, inverted v or k) should be used and on which bay. Can someone please chime in? I know it's not inverted V. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of structure.

Masonry and concrete structures don't benefit much from any of the three choices. They require either a shear wall of the same construction or just re-enforcing the walls on the side of the openings with additional rebars anchored in a foundation designed to support the uplifting and overturning moments.

If however, the structure is lightweight wood (type 5), there are many reasonably priced lateral load-bearing prefabricated walls, or the code recommended plywood shear wall with approved nailing, fasteners, anchors.

The only case where the braces you mention are going to be practical are steel frame structures and for those, one needs to know more about the section properties of the beams and foundation and the other parts of the building before making a decision.

Comment: The bracing is the only option i was given...

Comment: It is a wage question then. More detail is needed.